# c++ array. Looking for better solution

Tags: c++, homework

So i got an task from school.
Which ask's me to write a program tad creates an 2d array with 11 rows and 5 columns.
In which the first column starts with 2.0 and increments by 0.1 all the way up to 3.0.
Then in next column it should be devided by 1 so if x is 2.0 then 1 / x and goes trough all 11 rows.
then in next column it has to multiply by 2 so x^2 and repeat in every column up to x^4.
So so far i got it to do what i need , but i know there should be a better way to achieve this. as if there would be a task to go up to x^50 for example i imagine it would be pain to do with my way. as its hardcoded.

So here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 const int rows = 11;
 const int columns = 5;
 double x = 2.0;


 array<array<double, columns>,rows> A{};
 cout << setprecision(2);
 cout << fixed;
 cout << setw(2) <<"x" << setw(10) << "1/x" << setw(7) << "x^2" << setw(7) << "x^3" << setw(8)<< "x^4\n";
 cout << "------ ------ ------ ------ ------\n";
 A[0][0] = x;
 for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
 {
     A[i+1][0] = A[i][0] + 0.1;
     A[i][1] = 1 / A[i][0];
     A[i][2] = A[i][0] * A[i][0] * A[i][0];
     A[i][3] = A[i][0] * A[i][0] * A[i][0]* A[i][0];
     A[i][4] = A[i][0] * A[i][0] * A[i][0]* A[i][0] * A[i][0] ;
     for(int j = 0; j < A[0].size(); j++)
     {
         cout << A[i][j] << setw(4)  << " ";
     }
     cout << endl;
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

and here is how it's supposed to look:
[image]

Looking for suggestions or tips. I am strugling here.
And sorry for my english it's not my native.

Comment: You say "devided by 1" and "multiply by 2" but you do something different. And it's not x^2, either. Most of your table is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you just need to use [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) to raise a value to an arbitrary power, and add another `for`-loop to handle the repetetive work of filling in all the remaining columns:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
     A[i][0] = 2.0 + 0.1 * i;
     A[i][1] = 1 / A[i][0];

     for(int j = 2; j < A[i].size(); j++)
     {
         A[i][j] = std::pow(A[i][0], j);
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't even know about std::pow :D Learned something new today. Thanks man.

Comment: @DreamHacker It's a pretty basic function provided by the standard library. I suggest you browse through https://en.cppreference.com/w/ and see what other helpful functions there are. You don't have to remember everything, but just get a feel of what is out there, so next time you need something you know where to look.